# how to extend a pretrained transformer model configured with small max_position_embeddings to a longer one

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model, huggingface-tokenizers

suppose I want to use the existing pre-trained model.
https://huggingface.co/Salesforce/grappa_large_jnt/
as the initial checkpoint for finetuning.

This grappa model has max position embedding as 514 in config.json

> "max_position_embeddings": 514,

Now I want to extend this model from 514 to 1024 tokens. The first 0-513 embeddings are initialized with the pre-trained model, the rest (514-1023) are randomly initialized.

How to archieve this?

Comment: I am assuming that you want to extend *all* parts of the model such that they can handle 1024 tokens? In that case, I'm afraid it's not trivial, and you would be better of just straight up re-training from scratch...

Comment: Did you reach any conclusion regarding this? I am also interested